# Getting HTTP response with date before request date. Is that right?

Tags: http-headers, time-synchronization

Say I sent a HTTP request at Thu, 22 Jun 2017 10:30:30 GMT.

Is it right if I got `Thu, 22 Jun 2017 10:30:25 GMT` in response Date header?

Which could be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many servers and clients do not use NTP to synchronize their time to standard time. The response header should contain a timestamp from the server.

Time differences of seconds are common, and it is not unusual to have larger time differences.  There are sites like [time.is](https://time.is/) that will tell you how far the time on your computer is from standard time.

If you have access to the server, the command `ntpq -nc peers` will show how far the server is from standard time.  This only works it the server is running an `ntp` server.   Windows servers have slightly different commands.

If the response was served by a cache server, the date header could be from the original response.  However, for such a small differences I would expect the above explanation to apply.